# Quotient of a Riemann Surface: $i:C \to C$ such that $i([X,Y,Z])=[-X,Y,Z]$

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, riemannian-geometry, algebraic-curves

> **Problem:** Let $X,Y,Z$ be homogeneous coordinates in $\mathbb P^2\mathbb C$ and
>
> $$C=\{[X,Y,Z] \in \mathbb P^2\mathbb C \mid X^4 + Y^4 + Z^4=0\}.$$
>
> Let $i:C \to C$ be the map $i([X,Y,Z])=[-X,Y,Z]$. Calculate the genus of $C/i$.

**Thoughts:** $C$ is smooth of genus 3. $i^2=Id$. Morover $i$ is a ramified covering of index $2$ with four special points at $[0,a_i,1]$ with $a_i^4=-1$. I tried to study $f: C \to \mathbb P\mathbb C$ such that $f=\frac Y Z$ because it maps into the quotient as a map $f_i: C/i \to \mathbb P\mathbb C$. Since $f$ has 4 simple poles and 4 simple zeros given in pairs, $f_i$ has 2 simple poles and 2 simple zeros. We also find 4 ramification points at $[0,a_i,1]$ which remain the same. Thus $g=5$ by Hurwitz Formula.

This approach could be completely wrong anyway! The genus I found is even greater than the one of $C$ which is also weird!

Thanks!

Comment: you have to use the hurwitz formula for the quotient map $C \to C/i$

Comment: do you mean $X^4+Y^4+Z^4$ ?

Comment: @mercio Let's see: There are 4 ramification points of order 2 and the map has degree $2$ thus $g=1$. Is that right? What's wrong with my method tho? Thanks!!

Comment: $i$ is an automorphism and thus can not be ramified as a starting point.